# Ошибка при загрузке apk в google play (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass)

Tags: java, android, cordova

У меня проект на vue quasar.
Я создаю приложение с помощью cordova.
debugg версия полностью работает. Но когда я создаю aab файл для загрузки (google его опубликовал в play store), но приложение крашится.
Ошибка в консоли следующая (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass)
В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибка вообще неинформативна, по ней сложно сказать где у вас проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала посмотрите на запись тестирования от гугла, отловите момент где на эмуляторе приложение падает, дальше посмотрите в логи гугла, может там упоминается ваш класс, можно так же добавить в gradle.build:

```
defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion // your version 
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

[здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) есть доп информация. [Подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426853/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclass) на enSO